# How to use OpenCV cameraCalibrate without Imagesize

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, calibration, lidar

I am using cameraCalibrate function on openCV (C++), and I know imagePoints(2D) and objectPoints(3D). I have obtained ImagePoints and ObjectPoints 300 points each.
So I don't need image and I don't have image size. but I have to put image size to use the function. How can I subtitute OR use the function without image size. at first I wrote `None`, but it did't work. I am very new to Camera calibration code and I would really appreciate any advice I could get. Thank you.

**C++**

```cpp
cv::calibrateCamera(
    objpoints, imgpoints, cv::Size(gray.rows,gray.cols), cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, R, T
);
```

**PYTHON**

```py
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(
    objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None
)
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the calibration? You could try to put any imsgesize there (e.g. max x and y of your points?). I dont know whether it is really needed only used for initial guess of the principial point?!?

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-use-opencv-cameracalibrate-without-imagesize/9919

Comment: I'm currently calibrating between the lidar and the projector.

By calibrating between the 3D coordinates of the lidar and the 2D coordinates of the projector, I want to get the internal parameters and external parameters of the projector.

So for the imagepoints, I projected a certain pattern with the projector and put its pixel coordinates.

For the objectpoints, the three-dimensional coordinates of the pattern extracted from the lidar were put. 

And 'cv::calibrateCamera' requiers me to input imagesize. but I didn't use image. how do i put any imagesize?

Comment: Thank you for answering in such short notice. This problem has been eating at me for a while. I really hope someone here can shine some guidence.

Comment: You know the "pixel coordinates", so, I guess you also know the "image size".

Comment: e.g. When the projector projects 640x480 image for the entire projection angle range, the "image size" for this scene will be 640x480.